# Ruby windows-1250 encoding

Tags: ruby, encoding

I'm trying to get data from site with charset windows-1250
I have this code:

```
require 'open-uri'
p open('http://www.ceskybenzin.cz/mapa/0').read.force_encoding('Windows-1250').encode('UTF-8').scan /addMarker\( point, '(.*?) - (.*?) - (.*?) - (.*?)', 'green', (.*?), bublina, 0 \);/
```

and I'm getting data like:

```
["EuroOil", "Prun\u00E9\u0159ov ", "U\u0161\u00E1k", "Zat\u00EDm nezadan\u00FD kraj", "181"]
```

could someone tell me how to correctly get data from windows-1250 site

Thank you

Comment: Could you explain what data you expect to get? You need to be careful when inspecting and displaying output, that it is not simply the inspect output that is not matching your expectations (because it may "helpfully" escape extended characters in case the string ends up where the characters may not be displayable). Try printing the strings - I see `["EuroOil", "Prunéřov ", "Ušák", "Zatím nezadaný kraj", "181"]` when I do that, which looks valid at least . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a[0] => ["Kont.cz (NOVA-KONT)", "Praha 4", "Opatovsk\xC3\xA1", "Hlavn\u00ED m\u011Bsto Praha", "1"]
a.last => ["EuroOil", "Prun\u00E9\u0159ov ", "U\u0161\u00E1k", "Zat\u00EDm nezadan\u00FD kraj", "181"]

a.last.select { |i| puts i.encode("utf-8") } => produces

EuroOil
Prunérov
Usák
Zatím nezadaný kraj
181
```

Answer (score 1):

you have unicode-8 symbols in your data not win-1250.

to convert your current example string to correct text you can do this

```
data = ["EuroOil", "Prun\u00E9\u0159ov ", "U\u0161\u00E1k", "Zat\u00EDm nezadan\u00FD kraj", "181"]
data.select{|snippet| snippet.encode("UTF-8")}
```

=> ["EuroOil", "Prunéřov ", "Ušák", "Zatím nezadaný kraj", "181"]

if output you exampled is from console, then this is because console outputs  with utf-8 encoding not with encoding of your source site (and maybe parsing works correctly until it displays)